# How do I match accented characters with PHP preg?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I’d like to give my users the option to not only fill in letters and numbers, but also “special” letters like the “á”, “é”, etc. However, I do not want them to be able to use symbols like “!”, “@”, "%”, etc.

Is there a way to write a regex to accomplish this? (Preferably without specifying each special letter.)

Now I have:

```
$reg = '/^[\w\-]*$/';
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could use [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) to describe the characters:

```
/^[\p{L}-]*$/u
```

`\p{L}` describes the class of Unicode letter characters.

Comment: don't forget to add modifier _u_ at the end : `/u` to select UTF-8 mode … https://www.php.net/manual/fr/regexp.reference.unicode.php#118693

Answer (score 5):

What characters are considered "word-characters" depends on the locale. You should set a locale which has those characters in its natural alphabet, and use the `/u` modifier for the regexp, like this:

```
$str = 'perché';
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT@euro');
echo preg_match('#^\w+$#u', $str);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work either. But Gumbo's solution worked. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 4):

you can try with this regex:

```
$reg = '~[^\\pL\d]+~u';
```

which catch also accented characters

Comment: doesn't seem to work on my server. But Gumbo's answer worked. Thanks for the reply