# PHP Regex validate letters and Spanish accent

Tags: php, regex, encoding

How can I add/improvised my code so Spanish accent will be considered as valid in addition to normal alphabet (a-z)

I have the following in my code

```
public static function IsAlpha($s){
  $reg = "#[^a-z\s-]#i";
  $count = preg_match($reg, $s, $matches);
  return $count == 0;
}
```

Comment: Potentially duplicate question has the answer: [PHP: PREG: How to match special chars like a grave?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133758/php-preg-how-to-match-special-chars-like-a-grave)

Comment: It's a similar question, however, I still can't figure out how to integrate it with my existing regex.

Comment: @Wiseguy: you should post this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133758/php-preg-how-to-match-special-chars-like-a-grave), you could match accented characters using the full *Letter* [Unicode property](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) `\p{L}`. That includes regular `a-z` characters along with accented ones, so replace `a-z` in your expression with this like so:

```
$reg = "#[^\p{L}\s-]#u";
```

Note that to use this you need the [UTF-8 modifier `u`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) after your closing delimiter, as the docs say such Unicode "*character types are available when **UTF-8 mode** is selected*".

Comment: In my case I had to add the u modifier (UTF8) for it to work.

Comment: @user276648 Thanks, nice spotting. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the "u" unicode modifier!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [hexadecimal representation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) of each letter:

```
<?php
function IsAlpha($sString)
{

  $reg = "#[a-zA-Z\xE1\xE9\xED\xF3\xFA\xC1\xC9\xCD\xD3\xDA\xF1\xD1]+#i";
  $count = preg_match_all($reg, $sString, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
  return $matches;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r(IsAlpha("abcdefgh ñ á é í ño 123 asd asáéío nmas asllsdasd óúfl ÑABDJÓ ÚñÍÉ"));
echo '</pre>';
```

I do not know if there are all the letters, but you can add more with this [link](http://gias720.dis.ulpgc.es/Gias/Cursos/Tutorial_html/formtab.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com/docs/match):

```
pattern('[^\p{L}\s-]', 'u')->fails($s);
```