# Regex words with accents

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex

```
\b(t[úu]s*)\b
```

And i have this words:

```
tu (works)
tú (doesn't work)
tus (works)
tús (works)
```

Why can't I match `tú`?

Comment: I am using PHP and I am testing in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: but it's matching: http://rubular.com/r/CS7wRf7y4N

Comment: Perhaps this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2133758/1649067

Comment: Thanks Gustavo. I dont know why gskinner.com doesnt work with that. thanks

Comment: Apart from single pre-built character, there are also characters that has to be built from a base character + combining diacritics. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: I don't think regex is very unicode-aware. More bytes and characters than codepoints =( I might be wrong though. Maybe PHP has a modifier to enable unicode-awareness to make regexing for all `U` variants easier.

Answer (score 3):

If the regex doesn't match, the two characters differ.

"u with acute" can be expressed as the single Character `ú` (U+00FA) or by combining `u` (U+0075) with the *combining acute accent* character (U+0301) which gives a similar looking `ú`.

You have to either convert your input string or include both variants in you regular expression, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't that expression match `tú`?

That expression doesn't match `tú` because `\b` doesn't seem to recognize `ú` as a word character, and thus fails when used between non-word characters.

You could use something like this instead:

```
/(?<!\p{L})(t[úu]s*)(?!\p{L})/u
```

[`\p{L}`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) matches a unicode letter.

Comment: Hi, I try this (\p{L})(t[úu]s*)(\p{L})/u but doesnt work :(

Comment: @user2088434, why don't you copy the whole expression? You are missing several parts from it.