# Accented character validation in PHP

Tags: php, regex, unicode

What is a good one-liner php regex for checking first/last name fields with **accented characters** (in case someone's name was Pièrre), that could match something like:

```
<?php
$strErrorMessage = null;

if(!preg_match('/\p{L}0-9\s-+/u', trim($_POST["firstname"])))
  $strErrorMessage = "Your first name can only contain valid characters, ".
    "spaces, minus signs, or numbers.";
?>
```

This tries to use unicode verification, from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133758/php-preg-how-to-match-special-chars-like-a-grave), but doesn't work correctly. The solution seems pretty hard to google.

Comment: Huh? You want to exclude apostrophes why? Also, I've never heard of a name containing a "minus sign", though I'm aware of many containing hyphens.

Comment: @TRiG: I'm pretty sure that the "minus sign" and a hyphen (when typing) are exactly the same..

Comment: It's a long shot, but try also `\p{M}`

Comment: As a general rule, [do not try to validate name fields](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/15778/2131). Also, @Magictallguy, it's the same character as far as a programmer is concerned, yes, but calling it a minus sign in the context of a name is just plain weird.

Comment: @TriG: Aye, granted. I'll give you that :P

Comment: Sooooo... what exactly is the validation "rule"? Name may contain... characters?

Comment: A name contains, and should only contain characters. I've never heard of someone called 'florian :)' or '_-*-Sarah-*-_' on their official documents. There are some exceptions imho, like 'Jean-Pierre' and some cultures with names that are split. Therefore, my validation rule for a name should be unicode characters with optional dashes (or minus sign, but some international places have rarely heard of the word 'dash', or they use the word 'hyphen', so which word would you then use?), and perhaps a space.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the difficulty to validate a name, you need to put your characters into a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). `/\p{L}0-9\s-+/u` matches only on a sequence like "Ä0-9 ------". What you wanted to do is

```
/^[\p{L}0-9\s-]+$/u
```

Additionally I added [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), they ensure that the regex tries to match the complete string.

As ex3v mentioned you should probably add `\p{M}` to that class to match also combination characters. [See Unicode properties.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

```
/^[\p{L}\p{M}0-9\s-]+$/u
```

Comment: ...I had hoped that you would add the php code in this too.

Comment: @FlorianMertens, which code? `if(!preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{M}0-9\s-]+$/u', trim($_POST["firstname"])))
  $strErrorMessage = "Your first name can only contain valid characters, ".
    "spaces, minus signs, or numbers.";` ???