# Proper solution

Tags: php, character-encoding, fat-free-framework

I'm using F3 (Fat-Free Framework) for a project at work and have stumbled across a problem I can't seem to find any information about. Neither Google nor official F3 documentation has given me anything. Maybe I'm simply asking the wrong question. Here's the problem.

I have an array that looks something like this:
( city => type => building )

```
$places = array(
    'City A' => array(
        'special' => array(),
        'standard' => array('Campus', ),
    ),
    'City B' => array(
        'special' => array(
            'collect',
            'exam',
            'Brännässlan',
        ),
        'standard' => array(
            'Building A',
            'Building B',
            'Building C',
            'Building D (Library)',
            'Capitol',
            'Flair',
        ),
    ),
),
```

What I want to do is to check each building in the array to see if a corresponding dictionary variable has been set for it. I use `$f3->exists('dict_select_hus_arrayValue')` to check and it works fine until the function encounters a building with the letter 'ä' in it. If it does, it throws a 500 error with the text `Invalid hive key 'dict_select_hus_Brännässlan'`.

I assume it has to do with the encoding of the string, but I work in a purely UTF-8 environment and F3 should be able to handle it. Has anyone else encountered this and, more importantly, found a solution to the problem?

Comment: what does `exists` function have?

Comment: It returns true when the dictionary string is found, false when it isn't and crashes with a 500 when 'ä' is in the string (which I assume is not by design).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F3 doesn't allow language specific characters to be used as keys in hive. I'm not sure if this was intended or accidental, but the root cause of this problem lies in `&ref` method of `Base` class. You will find somewhere around line 244 a `preg_match('/^\w+$/',$parts[0])`. This will return `false` in your case as language specific characters are not within `\w`.

My advice would be to either [change this expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133758/how-do-i-match-accented-characters-with-php-preg) to include chars like the ones you use (you will need to remember about this modification in case you will later upgrade F3 or reset it for some reason) or [strip the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php) of them before checking with F3.

Answer (score 5):

It's true that a hive key is not allowed to have special chars, as @george007 has discovered. But this only applies for the very **first** hive key segment `$part[0]`. It's free to use it one level deeper. So `city.Brännässlan` should be fine. Just put your cities and dictonary entries into a deeper level. i.e:

`$f3->set('places',$places);`

lang file:

```
dict.select_hus.Brännässlan = XY
dict.select_hus.Kairo = YZ
```

php:

```
foreach ($f3->get('places') as $c_name => $city) {
  if ($f3->exists('dict.select_hus.'.$c_name)) {
    // it's there
  }
}
```

One NB from http://fatfreeframework.com/base#set

> Remember: Hive keys are case-sensitive. Furthermore, root hive keys
>   are checked for validity against these allowed chars: [ a-z A-Z 0-9 _
>   ]