# PHP Regex to accept only specific characters

Tags: php, regex

Can you help me?
I'm trying to make a PHP Regex to accept only: **A-Z**, **a-z**, **0-9**, **(**, **)**, **!** and accented words(**á**,**é**,**í**,**ó**,**ú** and **Á**,**É**,**Í**,**Ó**,**Ú**) to filter a list.

I tried everyting and searched so much, and I'm not getting succcess...
What should I do?

@edit:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[\p{L}-]*$/u", $line)){
```

I already tried using this from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133758/how-do-i-match-accented-characters-with-php-preg) but didn't worked.

What I'm trying to do? Accept only words that I want to filter this list:
[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mKVU.png)

@edit2: Already tried convertind to UTF8, using iconv, mb_convert_encoding, etc...

Comment: You say that you tried "everything," yet you showed us no code.  Please include your best code attempt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I match accented characters with PHP preg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133758/how-do-i-match-accented-characters-with-php-preg)

Comment: Thread updated.

Comment: Looks like you want to except specific CHARACTERS not specific words

Comment: Maybe `'~\b(?![A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)*\b)\p{L}\p{M}*+(?:-\p{L}\p{M}*+)*~u'`

Comment: Definition of allowed characters is not clear. Try something like [`/^[\p{Latin}0-9\s)(.,?!-]+$/u`](https://regex101.com/r/9JZ7TG/1/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hey, your code is what it comes closest of what I want., but is missing some special characters like: http://prntscr.com/itek9r.How can I fix?

Comment: @Amazingman I have no idea what you mean, please post the data in the *text* form, I cannot OCR it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It think this is what you are looking for:

```
if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s]*/", $line)){
    // line is ok
}
```

You can test here: https://regex101.com/r/4Ozxw2/1

Comment: I was kind of surprised how well this approach worked for a registered trademark symbol as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<?php

$strings = ['hash#', 'percent%', '!exc', 'ó','-',',','num1'];

foreach($strings as $v) {
    if (preg_match("/^[\p{L}A-Za-z0-9,!]*$/u", $v)) {
        print $v . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for :/

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```html
<?php

$strings = ['test(yes)h#', 'test2%', '!test3', 'ó','-',',...','test'];

foreach($strings as $v) {
    if (preg_match("/^[\p{L}A-Za-z0-9! | #\((.*?)\)#]*$/u", $v)) {
        print $v . '<br/>';
    }
}

?>
```

I think this will solve your issue.