# Allow spanish letters php like ñ áéíóú whit this function preg_replace();

Tags: php, function

With this function I can validate numbers and letters but I need to pass them the accents, the "ñ" and comma "," and blank spaces. PHP

I would like something like this:

```
$str = 'Caballeros Díaz, Caballeros Bilingüe';

$result= preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $str);
 //echo $result;

CaballerosDazCaballerosBilinge
```

allow this ñ áéíóú " , " numbers  (spanish letters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133758/how-do-i-match-accented-characters-with-php-preg Answers in this post might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php

Comment: thanks, just  i needed undertnn consept, just need add the letters allow,  like this: 
 `/[^A-Za-z0-9 .,áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ\-]/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I match accented characters with PHP preg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133758/how-do-i-match-accented-characters-with-php-preg)

Comment: These kind of questions tend to have really vague specs. Does it really need to be specific about Spanish? Do you explicitly need to strip e.g. Catalan characters like `Ç` or `Ŀ` so `Barça` becomes `Bara`? Also, is you application using UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but this might work:

```
$str = 'Caballeros Díaz, Caballeros Bilingüe';

$result = preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/u", '', $str);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php

Comment: Thanks, this code it's allow  work `/[^A-Za-z0-9 .,áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ\-]/`